# Writing my own block method

Tags: objective-c, singleton, objective-c-blocks

I am trying to follow through examples from other as well as Apple. I'm lost.

I have a singleton class that I use to handle my user logging in (challenges a web server, etc.).

I want to create a block I can call, pass in the username/password. The block will perform the web service calls then return if it was successful or not.

This is what i've manage to get working so far:

My singleton class looks like this:

**.h**

```
typedef void (^AMLoginBlock)(NSString *userName, NSString *password);

@interface AuthManager : NSObject
+ (id)sharedManager;

+ (bool)loginUserWithBlock:(AMLoginBlock)block;

@end
```

**.m**

```
@implementation AuthManager

+ (id)sharedManager
{
    static dispatch_once_t pred = 0;
    __strong static id _sharedObject = nil;
    dispatch_once(&pred, ^{
        _sharedObject = [[self alloc] init]; // or some other init method
    });
    return _sharedObject;
}

+ (bool)loginUserWithBlock:(AMLoginBlock)block {
    NSLog(@"im printing from AM");
    return true;
}

@end
```

I then call the method like so:

```
bool rtn = [AuthManager loginUserWithBlock:^(NSString *userName, NSString *password) {
        NSLog(@"im here in the block LVC.");
    }];
```

---

**My question is three parts:**

1. How do I write a completion handler for the block similar to `UIView animation...` block.
2. Is it a good idea to perform these web service calls from a block based implementation?
3. Should I be declaring the block method like so:

   `- (bool)loginUserWithBlock:(AMLoginBlock)block;`

instead of using `+(bool)loginUser..` since it is in a singleton class. Not sure if this will cause multiple instances of the singleton to be created.

My goal is to be able to call this block like you call `[UIView animation..]`. So I can simply do:

```
[AuthManager loginUserWithUsername:foo
                          password:bar1
                        completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                            if (finished)
                                //push new view controller.
                            else
                                //spit out error
                   }];
```

Answer (score 6):

## Completion Handler

You will want to copy the completion block to a class iVar:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) void (^completionHandler)(bool *);
```

Because you are saving the block, you need to have a non-class method take the block (see following for how to do this without violating your singleton). An example of your method could be:

```
- (void)loginUserWithUsername:(NSString *)username 
                     password:(NSString *)password 
                   completion:(void(^)(bool *finished))completionBlock
{
    // Copy the blocks to use later
    self.completionHandler = completionBlock;

    // Run code
    [self doOtherThings];
}
```

Then when your login code has finished its work, you can call the block - here I pass self.error, a `bool` to the block :

```
- (void)finishThingsUp
{
    // We are done with all that hard work. Lets call the block!
    self.completionHandler(self.error);

    // Clean up the blocks
    self.completionHandler = nil;
}
```

## Good Idea

Well, this is a philosophical question, but I will say this: Blocks in Objective-C allow you to write code that performs a single task and easily integrate it into many programs. If you chose to not use a completion handler in your login code you would need your login code to:

- Require that classes using it implement a protocol (as in a `LoginDelegate`)
- Use some other system of informing your code such as Key Value observing or Notifications
- Hard code it to only work with one type of calling class

Any of the above approaches are fine, I feel a block-based call back system is the simplest and most flexible. It allows you to just use your class without worrying about additional infrastructure (setting up notifications, conforming to protocols, etc. ) while still letting you reuse it in other classes or programs.

## Singelton

Methods that begin with a `+` in Objective-C are class methods. You cannot use class methods to manipulate iVars, as who would own that data?

What you can do is have a class method that always returns the same instance of that class, allowing you to have an object that can own data, but avoid ever having more than one of them.

[This excellent Stack Overflow answer has sample code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5043201/objective-c-store-variables-accessible-in-all-views).

Good Luck!